# can v change look of combobox of html by css or javascript or any other method

Tags: javascript, html, css

can v change look of combobox of html by css or javascript or any other method. i want the look of combobox of screen resolution window in windows 7.. its quite similar to a buttton ... can i make it....

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't styling select tag with css - except background (if I am wrong someone correct me).
You can use a jquery way. There are many plug in you can use to achieve a windows 7 appearance. I list you some of them.

[jQuery UI Selectmenu](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/)

[Stylish Select 0.4.1](http://www.prismstudio.co.uk/plugins/stylish-select/0.4/)

[Select Box Factory 2.1](http://www.headcircus.com/uiguy/selectboxfactory2.1/selectboxfactory.html)

You can find more in [Google results](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=jquery+styling+select+&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)